# Использование новых тегов html5

Tags: html, html5

Вопросы по использованию новых тегов html5.

Если в блоке `<aside>` у меня выложены небольшие статьи, можно ли использовать для каждой из них тег `<article>` ?

Если все содержимое страницы оборачивается в блок, для которого задается центрирование (задается `width` и `margin: 0 auto;` ) то нужно использовать див (например, `<div class="wrapper">` ) или новый тег `section` ?

Основной контент страницы это посты блога, я использую для них общий тег `section` и каждый отдельный пост кладу в `<article>` . Но в книге Кристофер Шмитт, Кайл Симпсон - "HTML5. Рецепты программирования", которую я сейчас читаю, сказано, что в теге `section` также **должен** присутствовать заголовок. Как быть, если у меня в верстке его нет и он мне не нужен?

Вопросы, собственно, по этой [верстке](http://web-portfolio1.narod.ru/index6/index.html). Не совсем понимаю, правильно ли я использую новые элементы html5 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - Да, можно. В одном блочном элементе могут быть другие :) Если ты определяешь для себя, что тот контент омжет тянуть на мини-статью - почему бы и не использовть article?

2 - я бы предпочел div class="wrapper". section подразумевает часть сайта, какой-то самодостаточный раздел (как section с новостями у тебя).

3 - можно без заголовка. Все эти **должен** не стоит пвоспринимать буквально и можно смело менять на **желателен**. Если не нужен заголовок, не используй. :) **Должен** быть html, head, body - остальное тебе решать.

Comment: Да, про использование article в aside я так и думала, но хотелось уточнить, и про div class="wrapper" тоже. Про section я все-таки до конца не совсем понимаю, как правильно, в той же книге сказано *Не используйте section, когда в содержимом нет естественного заголовка.*

Comment: Я не согласен с таким утверждением. Может быть секция сайта с картой, с рекламными блоками, с новостями или статьями. Если в последнем случае заголовок можно вывести, то в первых двух случаях он там лишний. Можно показывать блок с рядом реклам без надписи сверху "Реклама"  - это и так понятно.